# Query WMI remotely with PHP

Tags: php, windows, wmi, wmi-query

My current code looks like this:

```
define ( 'CPU_NAME', 'remote_server' );
$obj = new COM ( 'winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//' . CPU_NAME . '/root/cimv2' );
if ( is_object ( $obj ) ){ 
     $process = $obj->execquery ( "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process" );
}
```

Where would I put the login credentials for the remote_server?
I see that it would take a username and password, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: What do you mean by *"I see where it would take a username and password, but I'm not sure how to implement that."*? If you can see where the password would go - how can you not know where to put it?

Comment: I see that it accepts one, but not where it goes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do have DCOM enabled in php.ini, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php
    $obj = new COM ( 'winmgmts://localhost/root/CIMV2' );
    $fso = new COM ( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );    
    $wmi_computersystem    =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
    $wmi_bios              =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS");
    $processor             =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor");
    $PhysicalMemory        =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory");
    $BaseBoard             =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BaseBoard"); 
    $LogicalDisk           =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");


    foreach ( $wmi_computersystem as $wmi_call )
    {
        $model = $wmi_call->Model;
    }

    foreach ( $wmi_bios as $wmi_call )
    {
        $serial = $wmi_call->SerialNumber;
        $bios_version = $wmi_call->SMBIOSBIOSVersion;
    }

    foreach ( $processor as $wmi_processor )
    {
        $idprocessor = $wmi_processor->ProcessorId;
        $Architecture = $wmi_processor->Architecture;
        $Name = $wmi_processor->Name;
        $Version = $wmi_processor->Version;
    }
    foreach ( $PhysicalMemory as $wmi_PhysicalMemory )
    {
        $Capacity = $wmi_PhysicalMemory->Capacity;
        $PartNumber = $wmi_PhysicalMemory->PartNumber;
        $Name = $wmi_PhysicalMemory->Name;
    }

    foreach ( $BaseBoard as $wmi_BaseBoard )
    {
        $SerialNumber = $wmi_BaseBoard->SerialNumber;

    }
    foreach ( $LogicalDisk as $wmi_LogicalDisk )
    {
        $SerialNumberDisk = $wmi_LogicalDisk->VolumeSerialNumber;
        $FileSystem = $wmi_LogicalDisk->FileSystem;

    }

    echo "Bios version   : ".$bios_version."<br/>
          Serial number of bios  : ".$serial."<br/>
          Hardware Model : ".$model."<br/>
          ID-Processor : ".$idprocessor."<br/>
          Architecture-Processor : ".$Architecture."<br/>
          Name-Processor : ".$Name."<br/>
          Version-Processor : ".$Version."<br/>
          <hr>
          <hr>
          PhysicalMemory
          <hr>
          <hr>
          Capacity : ".$Capacity."<br/>
          Name : ".$Name."<br/>
          <hr>
          <hr>
          carte mere
          <hr>
          <hr>
          SerialNumber : ".$SerialNumber."<br/>
           <hr>
          <hr>
          disk
          <hr>
          <hr>
          SerialNumber : ".$SerialNumberDisk."<br/>
          FileSystem : ".$FileSystem."<br>
          ";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $strComputer = "YOURREMOTEHOST";
    $objSWbemLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
    $objSWbemServices = $objSWbemLocator->ConnectServer($strComputer, "root\cimv2", "DOMAIN\USER", "Password");
    $objSWbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;
    $obj = $objSWbemServices;
    $fso = new COM ( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );

    //... insert your code here

    //... insert your code here
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### CONNECTING

**For global admins**

```
define("NAMECOMP", 'COMP1'); // COMP1 - name or ip of local or remote computer 
$WMI= new COM ( 'winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//'. NAMECOMP.'/root/cimv2' );
```

**For with login and password**

```
$objLocator = new COM("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
$objService = $objLocator->ConnectServer(
                'ComputerName', //name/ip remote/local comp
                "root\cimv2",
                'login', //login remote/local comp
                'password', //password remote/local comp
                "MS_409",
                "ntlmdomain: YourDomain" //domain remote/local comp
            );
```

### GET INFORMATION

```
$CountCore=0;
foreach ($WMI->instancesof ( 'Win32_Processor' ) as $proc ) {
  ++$CountCore;
}
echo 'Count Core = ' . $CountCore;
```

add information of speed and socket processor

```
$CountCore=0;
foreach ($WMI->instancesof ( 'Win32_Processor' ) as $Processor) {
  ++$CountCore;
  $Speed=$Processor->CurrentClockSpeed;
  $Socket=$Processor->SocketDesignation;
}
echo 'count core = '.$CountCore;
echo 'speed = ' . $Speed. 'Mhz';
echo 'socket = '.$Socket;
```

get other information simple - just replace class for instancesof ('Win32_Processor')

[Information of classes WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394572(v=vs.85).aspx)

### SEND COMMAND

```
if ((($_GET['Reboot']==1) OR ($_GET['Shutdown']==1))) { 
 
  define("NAMECOMP", 'COMP1');
          
  $WMI= new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}//'. NAMECOMP.'/root/cimv2'); 
  
  foreach($WMI->instancesof('Win32_OperatingSystem') as $mp)  {
      if ($_GET['Reboot']==1) {
          $mp->Reboot; 
      }
      if ($_GET['Shutdown']==1) {
          $mp->Shutdown; 
      }
}
```

**Links:**

[WMI Isn't Working!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx)

[Component_Object_Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

[Win32 Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx)

[For Yii Framework](https://github.com/githubjeka/Harvester/tree/master/protected/models)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is not the newest but maby this info helps someone.
If you try to read or write Registy keys or installed Software class on a Remote Computer you need to pass the Architecture under the query should run. You can use something like this.

```
function Connect($server = "RemotePC",$namespace = "root/CIMV2",$impersonate = 3,$Architecture = 64,$userid = null,$password = null){
        try {
            $wbemnvs = new COM("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet");
            $wbemnvs->add("__ProviderArchitecture", $Architecture);
            $wbemnvs->add("__RequiredArchitecture", true);
            $wmiLocator = new COM("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
            $this->wmiNameSpace = $wmiLocator->ConnectServer($server, $namespace, $userid, $password,null,null,128,$wbemnvs);
            if($this->wmiNameSpace){
                $this->ConnectedServer = $server;
            }else{ return false; }
            if($impersonate){
                // mehr infos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
                $this->wmiNameSpace->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = $impersonate;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->wmiNameSpace = NULL;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

check out my wmi.class.php at: http://scbbb.blogspot.de/2014/02/wmi-via-php.html