# How can I use WMI from PHP

Tags: php, wmi

First of all I am sorry for the newbi question ! :D

I want to build a website to do excactly what psands in the following topic did:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2virtualization/thread/697eafc2-7778-488b-8774-7554f84de642

he built a website to manage virtual machiens such as creat/start/stop.... VMs using the WMI API for Hyper-v with asp.net

now he did it with ASP.NET , my question is can I do it with PHP ?
in another words does the API support PHP ?

Thanks ..

Comment: can you please give a short summary of the link's content. might make people more willing to consider your question.

Comment: Will he built a website to manage virtual machiens such as creat/start/stop.... VMs using the WMI API for Hyper-v with asp.net

Thanks Gordon

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with Hyper-V - HyperV exposes via standard windoqws API (WMI), as ell as many other things. So, the question is "how can I use WMI from PHP". Retgging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query WMI remotely with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848707/query-wmi-remotely-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
class wmiConnect
{
    // WMI connection to specified host
    protected $connection;
    /**
     * Create a new wmi instance.
     *
     * @param   string  $host       Host name or IP address to connect to
     * @param   string  $username   Local host user with rights to query WMI; normally a local admin
     * @param   string  $password   Password of local user account
     * @return  void                New wmi object
     */
    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null) {
        $wmiLocator = new \COM('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
        try {
            $this->connection = $wmiLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\\CIMV2', $username, $password);
            $this->connection->Security_->impersonationLevel = 3;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // -2147352567 means that we're unable to connect to the local host with a username and password.
            // Attempt connection again passing null values for username and password.
            if ($e->getCode() == '-2147352567') {
                $this->connection = $wmiLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\CIMV2', null, null);
                $this->connection->Security_->impersonationLevel = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get all properties of a WMI class.
     *
     * @param   string  $win32_class    Win32 class to retrieve data from
     * @return  object                  WMI collection object
     */
    public function getInfo($win32_class) {
        $WMIcollection = $this->connection->ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM ' . $win32_class);
        foreach ($WMIcollection as $WMIobj) {
            return $WMIobj;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a list of classes for WMI:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx

Hyper-v for 2012 on has a new namespace - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850078(v=vs.85).aspx