# PHP not waiting for VB script to complete

Tags: php, windows, shell, vbscript, wmi

Trying to write a php page that has a form that lets you type in a remote IP or Hostname, and retrieve basic info like RAM Size and HD size.

The code that processess the form data:

```
   $host = $_POST['host'];
   $cmd = "cscript /nologo remotehostinfo.vbs ".$host;
   $output = shell_exec($cmd);
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

This is the remotehostinfo.vbs code, the script does a WMI query to a remote host.

```vb
DIM arg
Set arg = wscript.Arguments
strComputer = arg(0)
On Error Resume Next
wscript.echo "Info"
wscript.echo "------"
'//////// Get Ram Amount
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colCSItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
For Each objCSItem In colCSItems
  ram = int(objCSItem.TotalPhysicalMemory/ 1048576)
Next
wscript.echo "RAM Size: " & ram
wscript.quit
```

When I run the script from the PHP page, it does not return the RAM size, but if I run the vb script from a command prompt it works just fine, anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Can PHP not run a vbscript that does a query of a remote host?

Comment: Does your command include the `> test.txt` when ran on the command line? Your script now writes the output to `text.txt` so you might aswell try to read that file using PHP.

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848707/query-wmi-remotely-with-php

Comment: Perhaps you should supply the full path to `cscript`.

Comment: @devator, sorry, forgot to remove that. It no longer includes that.

Comment: @bdsnoobs, the script runs. Otherwise I would get a "Could not find the file" error.

Comment: Also, make sure you escape the shell arguments! http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: @MartinSamson I will, as soon I can get this to work.