# WMI query to get remote IP info using PHP

Tags: php, com, wmic

```
$obj = new COM ( 'winmgmts://localhost/root/CIMV2' );
$fso = new COM ( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );    
$wmi_computersystem    =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
$wmi_bios              =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BIOS");
$processor             =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor");
$PhysicalMemory        =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory");
$BaseBoard             =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_BaseBoard"); 
$LogicalDisk           =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");


foreach ( $wmi_computersystem as $wmi_call )
{
    $model = $wmi_call->Model;
}

foreach ( $wmi_bios as $wmi_call )
{
    $serial = $wmi_call->SerialNumber;
    $bios_version = $wmi_call->SMBIOSBIOSVersion;
}
```

i have above code to get the localhost information.and it works well.
My question is, To get the remote machine info,where should i put user credentials(username,password of domain administrator)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21872171/2083490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an intermediary [WbemScripting.SWbemLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, something like this:

```
$loc = new COM( "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator" );
$obj = $loc->ConnectServer( "hostname", "rootcimv2", "user", "password" );
```

Answer (score 0):

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(~0);

$objLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");

$objService = $objLocator->ConnectServer( "hostname", "rootcimv2", "user", "password" );

$objService->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;

$values =$objService->execquery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

//$value = (array)$values;

$i = 0;

foreach ( $values as $wmi_call )
{

```
    echo $caption = $wmi_call->CAPTION;
    echo $csname = $wmi_call->CSNAME;
    echo $CurrentTimeZone = $wmi_call->CurrentTimeZone;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i;
    $i++;
```

}

This might help when user want to access wmi from server.
Cheers!!! Ajay Singh Rathore