# How can I work with my serverside smartcard via PHP?

Tags: php, smartcard

is it possible to communicate with a serverside smartcard via PHP?

My intention is to **connect the smartcard reader to the server** so I can send input to it and receive the result. I want to use it to create a custom pos system using "INSIKA" (http://www.insika.de/)

Are there any existing libraries I could use?
Is there any software I can use via `exec()` (for example)?

I could not find many information on this online since most people need to read a smartcard on the users pc - I don't need to do this.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the reader in the server as first step to make the whole APDU run, so [Query WMI remotely with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848707/query-wmi-remotely-with-php) can be a start.

If you need a source to build your APDU I use [this one](https://github.com/orouit/SmartcardFramework/tree/master/Smartcard_API/GemCard) for C# as a start point and then the INSIKA specifications they send to build all the commands.